# ndk-build can't find files under jni directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I have a very simple test project. Basically one native c file under jni (jni is
under the root of the project, in the same directory as 'src' 'res' etc). The make
file is the basically the simplest:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Error message is: make: *** No rule to make target ` '/native.c'. needed by...
Obviously ndk-build was trying to find the file under root. If I copy the file
to the root '/' or if I specify the full path of 'native.c' in the make file, 
then things are ok.

I also tried to output $LOCAL_PATH by $(warning, '$(LOCAL_PATH)') and found no problem.

Comment: What is the full path to your project root?

Answer (score 1):

Create Android.mk with the following content:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Put `native.c` in the same folder where your Android.mk is.

Run `ndk-build`

You will have the output as follows:

```
D:\12314\jni>ndk-build
"Compile thumb : native <= native.c
SharedLibrary  : libnative.so
Install        : libnative.so => libs/armeabi/libnative.so
```

Comment: Same, still can't find native.c if I don't specify the full path or put a copy under root.

Comment: My original Android.mk was like this. And it's under directory jni. But it couldn't find native.c (which was under jni also). So it's very strange. I added Application.mk to jni. I tried ndk-build under the project root directory (like directory 12314 in your example) and jni, same error message.

Comment: My example works even without Application.mk. I use Android NDK r8b.

Comment: It should work without Application.mk. It's really strange, I will re-install ndk-build, see what will happen.

Comment: Reinstalled android-ndk, still no luck. Really strange. Don't know why it won't search the LOCAL_PATH directory.